# Any way for a faster Python For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

Can anyone please let me know if the below for loop can be adjusted to be faster. the below for loop runs on a spreadsheet of almost 200k rows and it takes around 22 hours to compute. Any help would be appreciated.

So my initial spreadsheet have the 2 columns highlighted in green.

My code job is to fill in all the other columns in yellow according to the criteria in the code below.

My initial spreadsheet :

[image: My initial spreadsheet :]

My code (Sample to fill in just one column):

```
for i in range(0,len(rolling)):

    # Fill in the 3 Month OT
    rolling.iloc[i,9]=sum(rolling.fSM_OT[(rolling['PERIOD_DATE'].isin(pd.date_range(rolling.BO3M[i], rolling.PERIOD_DATE[i]))) &
    (rolling['CUSTOMER_ID']==rolling.CUSTOMER_ID[i]) &
      (rolling['SUPPLIER_ID']==rolling.SUPPLIER_ID[i]) 
         & (rolling['SUPPLIER_LOCATION_ID']==rolling.SUPPLIER_LOCATION_ID[i])])
```

Comment: Possibly, you should not be using explicit loops for these calculations. Why not *pick 1 loop*, create a *minimal working example*, and ask if it can be optimized. Also see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Yeah reduce down to minimal complexity then optimize as @jpp commented.

Take a look at this also, great way to get things like this done at speed with Python. http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/